# Unusual issue with HTML image and 'file://' specified src

Tags: html, image

I'm loading an image on the page with a 'file:///some_dir/image.jpg' src path. I can access the image in a regular tab using this path. Also, saving the page as HTML and using this path for the image works. However, the image does not load on the live page. In chrome it shows part of the alt text, and in firefox it shows a narrow strip. I have tried changing width and height but to no avail. Is there something I'm missing?

```
<img title="Click to enlarge" src="file:///Users/Aram/uploads/profile.image.985b0f707d972bf3.4372696242656464696e67616e645465657468696e67437269625261696c436f7665722e6a7067.jpg" class="profile-image">
```

**EDIT:**

I noticed I am getting this in the console:

> Not allowed to load local resource

Is there any way around this?

**EDIT 2:**

Since I could not access the image through an http path, I have decided to read it in as base64 data. For anyone else using web2py or another Python framework:

```
# Load the image data
import os
path = os.path.join(request.folder, 'uploads', filename)
data_uri = open(path, 'rb').read().encode('base64').replace('\n', '')
data = 'data:image/png;base64,%s' % data_uri
return html.IMG( _src=data, _class='profile-image', _title='Click to enlarge' )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Websites are not allowed to use local files on the user's computer. Use a relative path to from the html file's directory.

You can also encode and embed the image directly:

How to embed the encoded stuff: http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html
Python Encoding Instructions: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216635

Comment: That's what I figured, but if I can't use an http path to this image because of the web2py environment I'm using, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are trying to load a file directly off of a clients computer.  Browsers prevent this.

You can read about the exact details here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

It is called the Origin Policy.  It prevents malicious sites from directly loading files off of a clients computer.  Try using a relative path from your page to display the image.

In some situations (rare) I've used a light web server to host the site so that I could load the files from the server (as opposed to having it load off of what the browser sees, as a clients computer).

Comment: poor link, all it has to say on the subject is that :it is poorly defined" and even then I'm not entirely sure it is talking about images. Really, images can be included from other domains, so this isn't really relevant.