# open image in new tab after click on href link

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

after click on href link i want to display image on new tab but its not working ,and for my testing purpose i add a google link that is opening in new tab but image file is not opening in new tab...below i am giving my code.

```
var photoName = '<a href="D:/VS_Editor/Abc Static/new/pqr.Admin/UploadImage/' + response[i].DocumentName + '"  target="_blank">' + response[i].DocumentName + '</a></td>';
```

this is not woking ,but for my testing purpose is modified the code and used google link which is working and here below is that code

```
var photoName = '<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">' + response[i].DocumentName + '</a></td>';
```

- this is the path were i storing my image and wants to display.

> "D:/VS_Editor/Abc Static/new/pqr.Admin/UploadImage/' + response[i].DocumentName + '"

Comment: Double check `response[i].DocumentName` is matching the image name "exactly" cases sensitive, also ensure you can manually navigate to that path to ensure it exists or is accessible.

Comment: does `response[i].DocumentName` returns the image name with it's extension?

Comment: "D:/VS_Editor/Abc Static/new/pqr.Admin/UploadImage" You can't link to a file like that in a browser. You have to use http:// or https:// to reference a file name on the server. The browser client cannot natively read what is on the D: drive of the server (and a good thing, too)

Comment: `<a href="D:/VS_Editor/Abc Static/new/pqr.Admin/UploadImage/jpeg2_10514.jpg" target="_blank">jpeg2_10514.jpg</a>` this is code showing in debugger mode.

Comment: Hi ADyson then how i will use https here,will please tell me

Comment: `<a href="https://URL/of/file/on/webserver/image.jpg" ...etc` The folder structure will depend on where the file is held relative to your website's root, just as with any URL.

Comment: hi ADyson but now this is present in my local project folder

Comment: If it's a local project use the file protocol. e.g. file:///D:/VS_Editor/Abc Static/new/pqr.Admin/UploadImage/jpeg2_10514.jpg

Comment: Hi H77 its giving error not allowed to load local resource:file:///D:/VS_Editor/Abc%20Static/new/pqr.Admin/UploadImage/jpeg2_10514.jpg

Comment: You can't use a webpage to display images from the local user's computer in this way. Security policy prevents it. A website cannot access the local computer - think of the damage hackers could do if this was possible, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782360/unusual-issue-with-html-image-and-file-specified-src gives one explanation.